How authentic is this hadith (sabab al-nuzul of 65:4)?

Abu Ishaq al-Muqri’ informed us> Muhammad ibn ‘Abd Allah ibn Hamdun> Makki ibn ‘Abdan> Abu’l-Azhar> Asbat ibn Muhammad> Mutarrif> Abu ‘Uthman ‘Amr ibn Salim who said: “When the waiting period for divorced and widowed women was mentioned in Surah al-Baqarah, Ubayy ibn Ka‘b said: ‘O Messenger of Allah, some women of Medina are saying: there are other women who have not been mentioned!’ He asked him: ‘And who are they?’ He said: ‘Those who are too young [such that they have not started menstruating yet], those who are too old [whose menstruation has stopped] and those who are pregnant’. And so this verse (And for such of your women as despair of menstruation…) was revealed”.

I read that Al-Hakim authenticated it, but also that Ibn-Al-Arabi weakened it heavily (he didn’t deem it as authentic) according to Ibn Ashur but I can’t find this anywhere else. Al-Wahidi also provided a chain from Kallad ibn al-Nu‘man ibn Qays al-Ansari through Muqatil but I also can’t find the full chain anywhere. Is any of the chains of this hadith sahih? Al-Suyuti has many others as well like through Abd-al-Razzaq and Ibn-al-Mundhir but nobody ever seems to care about the authenticity of all these chains. Anybody who knows Arabic and has access to these sources, can you help me out?

I’d like to tag @Medi1Saif in the meanwhile because after reading some of your replies I think you’re one of the few who can help me here
